# Efeitos ao clicar em um botão

Tags: html, css

Eu gostaria de saber como posso adicionar um efeito ao clicar em um botão, eu estou usando HTML5 e CSS.

Eu adicionar um efeito com :HOVER, que assim que o mouse é posicionado sobre botão o background do mesmo é alterado, porém gostaria de um efeito que ao **clicar** no botão o efeito mudança na cor seja ativado.

Obrigado!

Comment: Da uma olhada nas propriedades `:active` e `:visited`  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1

Answer (score 1):

nesse caso você terá que usar JavaScript. Tente aplicar o seguinte código.

```
<style>
    button{
        border: 0;
        padding: 35px 50px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<script>

function mudaCor(el){
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}

</script>


<button onclick="mudaCor(this)">Clique</button>
```

No caso a função JavaScript está pegando uma cor randomica, caso queira uma cor padrão basta trocar o codigo hexadecimal. Veja no exemplo a baixo

el.style.backgroundColor = '#069';